# Conditions in Perl loops and performance

Tags: perl

There are many idioms in Perl with the using of operators/functions/subprograms/methods in loop conditions. Books advice use them!
But as I understand these conditions are calculated each iteration. Am I right?

Perl 5:

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash) { ... }
for my $value (values %hash) { ... }
```

Perl 6:

```
for 'words.txt'.IO.lines -> $line { ... }
while $index < $fruit.chars { ... }
```

Why programmers don't assign condition to some variable before loop and use this variable in loop? It would increase speed. So the first example would look like this:

```
my @array = keys %hash;
foreach my $keys (@array) { ... }
```

Comment: It's a fair question, and it's well-founded. But that problem with the loop condition being re-evaluated is only a problem in languages that have C-style for loops. Perl technically supports C-style loops, but it strongly favors for-each loops, which don't have that problem in any language that has them.

Comment: Thank you. What about the last example: `while $index < $fruit.chars { ... }`? Is it good to call _chars()_ method on each iteration? I read this example in Perl 6 book.

Comment: `while` loops would still evaluate the condition at every iteration. So it depends on what `chars` does. If `chars` is a cheap operation, I would leave it as is, as I find it cleaner to write that way. If it's expensive, then yeah it should be moved. Of course, it's also possible that the `while` loop is removing elements, so we may actually *need* `chars` to be reevaluated each time. So, not necessarily, but it depends on the situation.

Comment: `chars()` method returns the length of the string. It is Perl 6 equivalent of Perl 5 `length` operator. So it returns the same value each iteration. I don't know whether the Perl 6 compiler is smart enough to optimize this loop so the method will be called only one time. I'm confused [the popular book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920065883.do) do not do any manual optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

The condition is only calculated initially (before the loop starts) so I do not think it would increase the speed to precalculate the array before the loop.. Example:

```
for my $key (get_keys()) {
    say $key;
}

sub get_keys {
    say "Calculating keys..";
    return qw(a b c d);
}
```

**Output**:

```
Calculating keys..
a
b
c
d
```

Comment: Thank you. I came to Perl from C. In C there is another bahavior, no any condition precalculations so functions should not be called like that: `for (i = 0; i < fn(); i++);`

Comment: Hope the Perl 5 interpeter and Perl 6 compiler are smart enough to do condition calculation only one time at start.

Comment: Perl has two unrelated types of loops that use the same `for` and `foreach` keywords (which are synonyms). If you construct it with the same syntax as you would in a C `for` loop, it is actually equivalent to a `while` loop which does evaluate its condition (the second statement) and iteration code (third statement) each iteration. The other form, more commonly referred to as a "foreach loop" though it can also use either keyword, does not have a condition but simply evaluates a list of items to iterate through once, and aliases each item to the iterator.

Comment: See the documentation for [For Loops](https://perldoc.pl/perlsyn#For-Loops) and [Foreach Loops](https://perldoc.pl/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops). Perl 6/Raku is an unrelated language, I can't speak to how for or foreach (or other syntax it may have) work there.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash) { ... }
for my $value (values %hash) { ... }
```

The `for` and the `foreach` are synonymous in Perl, so aside from the fact that your two example snippets are operating on different parts of the hash, they're the same thing.

Ok, so here's what happens internally:  In each case all keys, or all values are calculated as a list, and then the looping construct iterates on that calculated list. There is an internal check, but that check is only to see if the loop has reached the offset of the last element in the list yet.  That is a cheap operation in the underlying C code.  To be clear, `keys` and `values` are *not* called on each iteration. The list of things iterated over is computed only once at the beginning of the loop.

Also, `$key` and `$value` are aliases to the actual key or the actual value, not copies. So there is no per-iteration copy made.

The nuance that is often missed is the fact that the iteration list is precomputed upon entering the loop.  That is why it's considered a terrible idea to do this:

```
foreach my $line (<$file_handle>) {...}
```

...because the entire file must be read and held in memory at once before the first line can be processed.  The fact that a list must be available internally first is typically an acceptable memory trade-off for things that are already held in memory to begin with. But for external sources such as a file there's no guarantee that available memory can hold the whole thing -- particularly if it's some endless stream. Consider this code:

```
open my $fh, '<', '/dev/urandom';
say ord while <$fh>;
```

It will never terminate, but will emit a constant stream of ordinal values. However, it does not grow in memory usage.

Now change the second line to this:

```
say ord for <$fh>;
```

This will appear to hang while it consumes all of the system's memory attempting to retrieve the entire contents of /dev/urandom (and endless stream). It must do this before it can start iterating, because that's how a range-based foreach loop works in Perl, and some other languages.

So a range based foreach loop is inexpensive in its computational overhead, but in some cases potentially expensive in its memory footprint.

Speaking to your final example:

```
my @array = keys %hash;
foreach my $keys (@array) { ... }
```

It doesn't make an appreciable difference, and may actually be slower or consume more memory.  When I compare the two approaches with a hash of 100000 elements the difference between the two is only 2%, or within the margin of error:

```
         Rate   copy direct
copy   35.9/s     --    -2%
direct 36.7/s     2%     --
```

Here's the code:

```
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my %hash;
@hash{1..100000} = (1..100000);


sub copy {
    my @array = keys %hash;
    my $b = 0;
    $b += $_ foreach @array;
    return $b;
}

sub direct {
    my $b = 0;
    $b += $_ foreach keys %hash;
    return $b;
}

cmpthese(-5, {
    copy => \&copy,
    direct => \&direct,
});
```

Comment: Everything is clear now, many thanks for your long and detailed answer! If you have any information about the Perl 6 book examples, it would be great.